# longtable on dedicated tables page

Tags: tables, longtable

I have written a document that includes many tables, so I have chosen to place all tables at the end of the document, invoked via the [p] option in the table environment. I now have to include a long table via the longtable environment, and am wondering if there is an equivalent form of the [p] option here (or at least some workaround).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `p` option does not put the tables at the end of the document. It puts the floating object on floating pages without text. Each `\clearpage` can force the pages to be output before end of document, for instance.

You can use package `endfloat` to move the tables to the end of the document.
Even `longtable` environments can be put there, if they are declared as tables for `endfloat`. Example follows. See the package documentation for more options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[
  tablesonly,
  notablist,
  nomarkers,
]{endfloat}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{longtable}{table}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\begin{table}
  \caption{First table}
\end{table}
\begin{longtable}{l}
  \caption{Long table}\\
  a\\
  b\\
\end{longtable}
\begin{table}
  \caption{Last table}
\end{table}
\section{Last section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why doesnt it work for me? It says command \longtable* already defined

Comment: @user3032689 I do not see any relation to the question or answer. Please, make a proper question with a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), the pasted error message (with line number, ...), and the version list, generated by adding `\listfiles`.